# Por que este mysqli_fetch_assoc retorna null?

Tags: php

Quando eu executo o código abaixo, ao chegar na linha `$user_image = $row['user_image'];`, a variável `$row` é atribuída como null e o loop é encerrado, porém, se eu retirar o else o código é executado normalmente e a variável `$user_image` recebe o dado vindo do banco de dados. Por que isto acontece?

```
    $user_image= $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $user_image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


    if(empty($user_image)){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = {$user_id}";
        $search_image = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if (!$search_image) {
            die("Error: " . mysqli_error($connection));
        }

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_image)) {
            $user_image = $row['user_image'];
        }

    } else {
       move_uploaded_file($user_image_tmp, "../users-images/" . $user_image);
    }
```

Código em que a atribuição funciona corretamente:

```
    $user_image= $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $user_image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($user_image_tmp, "../users-images/" . $user_image);

    if(empty($user_image)){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = {$user_id}";
        $search_image = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if (!$search_image) {
            die("Error: " . mysqli_error($connection));
        }

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_image)) {
            $user_image = $row['user_image'];
        }

    }
```

Observação: sei que a função `move_uploaded_file` retorna false caso o arquivo não seja válido e posso retirar este else do código, a minha intenção com a pergunta é entender porque este comportamento acontece.

Comment: Você utiliza a variável `$row` depois desse código?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Não, apenas nesse trecho.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Versão do PHP: 7.0.10